# C++ inheritance class. Which destructor will be used ?

Tags: inheritance

I'm learning C++ and I'm just getting into  inheritance classes.

```
class Seller {};

class Client : public Seller{};

Seller * ptr = new Client;
```

my question is when i use `delete ptr` which destructor will be used ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without virtual destructor only Seller::~Seller will be called.